# How to Customize Bootstrap 4.3 from BootstrapCDN

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to customize the Bootstrap 4.3 BootstrapCDN from the link from an external css file but I can't seem to do it.

I have positioned the custom css file below the bootstrap one which should override it. Does anybody know why this isn't working?

What I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

EDIT:

I am trying to change the `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">` class

Comment: what class you are trying to customize or overwrite ? CSS specificity decides the property to be used and only order in case of same weight of properties

Comment: Read up on CSS Specificity

Comment: @NagaSaiA the ```<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">``` class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it is a class in bootstrap you want overridden, you would need to add something like this: `.class {
   color:red !important;
}`

It is basically saying like apply this style. It will have priority over other styles the same class has, regardless of order in your stylesheet.